# Create boolean list based on index ranges in python

Tags: python

For some reason I am trying to create a boolean list of given length with the default `False`. Furthermore I know the index range(s) to be set to `True`.
I have to do that several times and for readability dont want to write out every list manually (neither with `0` and `1` and convert it), but write the actual index ranges, e.g. `range(2, 5)`.

I would like to have one-liner for every variable, but I simply do not seem to be able to get this done.

```py
index_length = 10
raw = [False] * index_length
# raw = np.array(raw)
var1 = [
  list(range(2,5)) + list(range(6,9)),
  list(range(0, 9),
  [],
]
```

Iterating through `var1` should result in a new variable `var2` as stated below, whereas the elements can either be binary integer or boolean values.

```py
var2 = [
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
```

I dont need a function which iterates through every element of the sublists of `var1`, but something like this.

```py
var2 = [None] * len(var1)
for idx  in var1:
  var2[idx] = ...
```

I thought there must be some list comprehension or something, but I failed for quite some time now. I tried using the raw list/numpy array but couldnt assign it to `var2` and edit the boolean values in one line
Maybe it is so easy I dont see it, maybe it is not possible at all, maybe python is not designed to do that but Id like to try anyways.

PS: I have spent that much time on it now, that I cant tell if my question explains my problem well, if not I am sorry in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert each sub-list in `var1` to a set, so that you can iterate an index through the range of `index_length` to efficiently test if the current index is in the set:

```
[[i in s for i in range(index_length)] for s in map(set, var1)]
```

This returns:

```
[[False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, False],
 [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False],
 [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]
```

Note that the expected output in your question has unnecessary values at index 0 and 6 in each sub-list, which are presumed to be typos on your part.

Comment: thank you, truth values with `in` was exactly what I had in mind...somewhere hidden deep in my mind. 
You are right my expected output is wrong (in addition of being to long), even though I dont agree with your stated indices entirely. Anyways, your output is right and I edited mine.